# Using Ubuntu 21.10 and trying to install php-dev, getting libpcre2-dev : Depends: libpcre2-8-0

Tags: apt, dependencies, php

can someone help me? I am trying to install php-dev using this command `sudo apt install php-dev`, but I am getting this error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libpcre2-dev : Depends: libpcre2-8-0 (= 10.37-0ubuntu2) but
10.38-2+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
                Depends: libpcre2-16-0 (= 10.37-0ubuntu2) but 10.38-2+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
                Depends: libpcre2-32-0 (= 10.37-0ubuntu2) but 10.38-2+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to reinstall and install php again, but did not work.

I am using Ubuntu 21.10 with

```
PHP 8.0.8 (cli) (built: Sep 11 2021 04:17:39) ( NTS ) Copyright (c) The PHP Group Zend Engine v4.0.8, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.8, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

`apt-cache policy php-dev` gets me this

```
php-dev:   Installed: (none)   Candidate: 2:8.0+82~0build1   Version table:
     2:8.0+82~0build1 500
        500 http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main i386 Packages
```

output from `egrep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d` is

```
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish main universe restricted multiverse #Added by software-properties
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish-updates main universe restricted multiverse #Added by software-properties
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish-backports main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security main universe restricted multiverse #Added by software-properties
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/dart_stable.list.distUpgrade:deb [arch=amd64] https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian stable main # забранен при надграждане до groovy забранен при надграждане до hirsute
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list.save:deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/ # забранен при надграждане до impish
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nordvpn.list:deb https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable main # забранен при надграждане до groovy забранен при надграждане до hirsute забранен при надграждане до impish
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/dropbox.list.distUpgrade:deb [arch=i386,amd64] http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu disco main # забранен при надграждане до groovy забранен при надграждане до hirsute
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/dart_stable.list.save:deb [arch=amd64] https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian stable main # забранен при надграждане до groovy забранен при надграждане до hirsute забранен при надграждане до impish
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list.distUpgrade:deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nordvpn.list.save:deb https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable main # забранен при надграждане до groovy забранен при надграждане до hirsute забранен при надграждане до impish
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list.dpkg-old:deb http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable main # забранен при надграждане до groovy
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/linrunner-ubuntu-tlp-focal.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_repo_protonvpn_com_debian-groovy.list.distUpgrade:deb https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian unstable main # забранен при надграждане до hirsute
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list:deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/ # забранен при надграждане до impish
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/slack.list.distUpgrade:deb https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian/ jessie main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list.distUpgrade:deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ stable steam # забранен при надграждане до groovy забранен при надграждане до hirsute
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/dart_stable.list:deb [arch=amd64] https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian stable main # забранен при надграждане до groovy забранен при надграждане до hirsute забранен при надграждане до impish
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nordvpn.list.distUpgrade:deb https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable main # забранен при надграждане до groovy забранен при надграждане до hirsute
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list.distUpgrade:deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list.distUpgrade:deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list.distUpgrade:deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main # забранен при надграждане до groovy забранен при надграждане до hirsute
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/audio-recorder-ubuntu-ppa-groovy.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/audio-recorder/ppa/ubuntu/ hirsute main # забранен при надграждане до hirsute
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/dropbox.list:deb [arch=i386,amd64] http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu disco main # забранен при надграждане до groovy забранен при надграждане до hirsute забранен при надграждане до impish
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list.save:deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free # забранен при надграждане до impish
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/git-core-ubuntu-ppa-groovy.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu/ hirsute main # забранен при надграждане до hirsute
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main # забранен при надграждане до groovy забранен при надграждане до hirsute забранен при надграждане до impish
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free # забранен при надграждане до impish
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-hirsute.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/ hirsute main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-hirsute.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/ hirsute main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list.save:deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main # забранен при надграждане до groovy забранен при надграждане до hirsute забранен при надграждане до impish
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/slack.list:deb https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian/ jessie main # забранен при надграждане до impish
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/slack.list.save:deb https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian/ jessie main # забранен при надграждане до impish
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-hirsute.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu/ hirsute main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-hirsute.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu/ hirsute main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/dropbox.list.save:deb [arch=i386,amd64] http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu disco main # забранен при надграждане до groovy забранен при надграждане до hirsute забранен при надграждане до impish
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list:deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ stable steam # забранен при надграждане до groovy забранен при надграждане до hirsute забранен при надграждане до impish
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list.save:deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ stable steam # забранен при надграждане до groovy забранен при надграждане до hirsute забранен при надграждане до impish
```

Comment: Please add `egrep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d` to your question.

Comment: @nobody, done..

Comment: Do you need ppa:ondrej/php ppa?  If not `sudo ppa-purge ppa:ondrej/php`

Comment: Why I am getting `sudo: ppa-purge: command not found`

Comment: `sudo apt install ppa-purge`

Comment: `Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: ondrej php` after running `sudo ppa-purge ppa:ondrej/php`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130727/discussion-between-dimitar-and-nobody).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we could revert packages from ppa's that are newer as from ubuntu sources with apt pinning.

```
sudo apt install  apt-show-versions
```

To identify how many packages are involved run

```
 apt-show-versions | fgrep newer
```

If are not many packages listed you have a good chance to fix brocken depencecies.

[community wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto)

The right values you can get from the output from

```
apt-cache policy
```

Note: Make a backup first and draw an iso so you can make a clean install. apt pinning is the last ditch to set things right
It can work but it is not guaranteed